# Hay manera de cambiar los estilos de la barra vertical en un input de texto?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo aproximadamente 1 hora buscando alguna propiedad que me indique como cambiar el | de los inputs de texto hay alguna manera ?

me refiero a el | que aparece y desaparece a medida de que se escribe

Comment: con la propiedad cursor en css
http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_13/personalizar_el_cursor.html

Comment: No, eso modifica el aspecto del cursor del mouse pero no la línea vertical que aparece dentro una vez que das click al input

Comment: No sigas buscando no la hay, puedes simular el mismo efecto en javascript, pero tendrías que componer un nuevo input, con todas las interacciones y agregar el efecto de un | falso al final. Hay alguna forma de re-crearlo con solo css, pero toca experimentar y no en un input, sino más bien en otro elemento tipo div y pasar el valor con javascript. Ahora si te refieres al cursor, basta con la propiedad **cursor: pointer**.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez si no existe propiedad para hacerlo ! solo para cambiar el color, veo muy tedioso hacerlo con javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes modificar el color con caret color

```
input{
  caret-color: red;
}
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: genial no conocía esa propiedad, se le pueden aplicar otros estilos?

Comment: Es la única que conozco, también puedes jugar con el text-shadow y el color del input algo así como esto https://codepen.io/fxm90/pen/MpGQwL

Comment: Si solo desea cambiar los inputs de texto, no debería ser mejor input[type=text] ?

Comment: correcto esta es la unica propiedad que he podido encontrar